# Image of circle being shown as a square in OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, textures, pyopengl

Using pyGame and pyOpenGL, I have created a 2D surface, I used this 815x815 PNG created in Photoshop as a texture:
[image: Image I'm using as a texture]

Here is how I'm loading the image, using pygame, and converting it into a texture.

```
pygame.init()
display = (800,600)
pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
myTex = pygame.image.load('0.png')
myTex = myTex.convert_alpha()
myTexData = pygame.image.tostring(myTex, 'RGBA', 1)
myTexID = 0
glGenTextures(1, myTexID)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, myTexID)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, myTex.get_width(), myTex.get_height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, myTexData)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
```

Here is the code I'm using to draw the square and the texture.

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE)
glBegin(GL_QUADS)
glVertex2fv((-1,-1))
glTexCoord2f(0,1)
glVertex2fv((-1,1))
glTexCoord2f(1,1)
glVertex2fv((1,1))
glTexCoord2f(1,0)
glVertex2fv((1,-1))
glTexCoord2f(0,0)
glEnd()
```

Here is what happens when I run the code. 
[image: OpenGL screenshot]
How do I get the texture to display properly, and why does this happen?

**EDIT**

It is some kind of transparency error, as changing the background of the image from transparent to white fixes the problem, however, convert_alpha() did not solve the problem. Also, I don't know why this is being downvoted, it is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the culprit is transparency.  Depending on how you created the png, the circle is going to have at least some pixels that are transparent to a certain degree.  If pygame doesn't know those transparency values, it will render it as a the base color, regardless of whether the pixel should be visible or not.  When you read [the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load), there is this blurb about pygame.image.load:

> For alpha transparency, like in .png images use the convert_alpha() method after loading so that the image has per pixel transparency.

In the comments, there is a user created function (by anonymous, so... try at your own risk) that uses this method:

```
def load_image(file, colorkey=False):
    file = os.path.join('data', file)
    try:
        image = pygame.image.load(file)
        colorkey = image.get_at((0, 0))
        if colorkey is True:
            image.set_colorkey(colorkey, pygame.RLEACCEL)
    except:
        print 'Unable to load: ' + file
    return image.convert_alpha() #Convert any transparency in the image
```

You could try using that, or I have a feeling you can simply:

```
myTex = pygame.image.load('0.png')
myTex = myTex.convert_alpha()
```

Comment: Neither made any difference. The PNG was created using Photoshop.